Angular dynamic reactive form with dynamic dropdown values
I'm trying to create a form working like that:

Click a 'Add filter' button
A dropdown is showing, values in this dropdown are coming from a request to an endpoint, with different types (default values in filterList)
Select a value in this dropdown -> depending on selection type, you display an input text, a checkbox or an input number, and hide the dropdown.

Here is my atempt but this is not working as expected, checkbox is showing but valueChanges is not triggered when ticking it. Can someone point me in the good direction?:
Template (I only added the checkbox for now):
<form [formGroup]="filterFormGroup">
  <div formArrayName="filter">
    @if (filterArray.length) {
      @for (filterItem of filters.controls; track filterItem; let i = $index) {
        <div class="filter-card" [formGroupName]="i">
          @if (filterArray[i]) {
            @switch (filterArray[i].filterSelect) {
              @default {
                <div class="array-select">
                  <mat-form-field class="query-filter-input" floatLabel="never">
                    <mat-select
                      placeholder="Select Function"
                      (selectionChange)="onfilterSelect($event, i)"
                      data-cy="query-form-function-select"
                    >
                      @for (filter of filterList; track filter) {
                        <mat-option
                          [value]="{ type: filter.type, value: filter.value }"
                        >
                          <div>
                            {{ filter.title }}
                          </div>
                        </mat-option>
                      }
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
              }
              @case (10) {
                <mat-checkbox
                  [formGroupName]="filterArray[i].filterValue"
                  class="example-margin"
                  >Check me!</mat-checkbox
                >
              }
            }
          }
        </div>
      }
    }

    <div class="button-container">
      <kx-ui-button
        variant="secondary"
        ariaLabel="Add Filter"
        (click)="onAddFilter()"
        dataCy="query-form-add-filter"
        leadingIcon="add"
        >Add Filter</kx-ui-button
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

And the component:
  @Output() filterModel = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() statusChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

  @Input()
  set filterModelForm(filterModel: any) {
    console.log(filterModel);
  }
  @Input() filterList: filters[] = [
    { title: 'Boolean Filter', type: 10, value: 'booleanFitler' },
    { title: 'String filter 1', type: 4, value: 'stringFilter1' },
  ];

  filterArray: filterArray[] = [];
  filterFormGroup = new FormGroup({
    filter: new UntypedFormArray([]),
    filters: new UntypedFormArray([]),
  });

  get filters(): any {
    return this.filterFormGroup.controls['filter'] as UntypedFormArray;
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }

  onfilterSelect(event: MatSelectChange, index: number): void {
    console.log('ib filter select', event);
    const filterSelect = event.value.value;

    this.filters.push(
      this.formBuilder.group({
        [filterSelect]: [''],
      }),
    );
    this.filterArray[index].filterSelect = event.value.type;
    this.filterArray[index].filterValue = filterSelect;
  }

  onAddfilter(): void {
    console.log('filter ARRY', this.filterArray);
    this.filterArray.push({
      filterSelect: 0,
      filterValue: '',
    });
    this.filters.push(
      new FormGroup({
        boolean: new FormControl(false),
        string: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        number: new FormControl(0),
      }),
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filterFormGroup.valueChanges

      .subscribe((model) => {
        console.log('emit model', model);
        // this.filterModel.emit(model);
      });

  }


  export interface filters {
    title: string;
    type: number;
    value: string;
  }
  
  interface filterArray {
    filterSelect: number;
    filterValue: string;
  }


The checkbox is a form control, not a form group (grouping of form controls, used for object type datastructures ( object containing form controls) ), so you should use formControlName
@case (10) {
  <mat-checkbox
    [formControlName]="filterArray[i].filterValue"
    class="example-margin"
    >Check me!</mat-checkbox
  >
}


Thx for your answere. I can make it work for the second one, but I think I have an issue with
this.filters.push formGroup on onAddFilter. It is adding it when selecting the checkbox:
{
"boolean": false,
"string": "",
"number": 0
},
{booleanFitler: true}

@SaHagin please create a working example on stackblitz.com with the steps the reproduce the issue for debugging.
